# Как решить проблему прописываем пути к базе данных?

Tags: c#, wpf

Постоянно надо строчку писать

```
string path = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=E:\Project\project\Мой программы\Практика\Profile\Profile\DataBase\DatabaseCasMed.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

Я написал такой код,он подходит если база данных в bin,если в другой папке бд я скину проект кому-то будут проблемы.

```
string pathD = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName), @"DataBase\DatabaseCasMed.mdf;");
string path = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;" + @"AttachDbFilename=" + @pathD + @"Integrated Security=True";
```

Написал код на .bat там Кракозябры в пути за русских слов.

```
@echo Off
SET  path=%cd%
echo %path%
@echo %path% > E:\pcc.txt
pause
```

Comment: что мешает использовать относительный путь до БД? Почему бы саму строку соединения  ещё и в конфиг не загнать?

Comment: И неплохо бы ещё использовать [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Я нашел решение**

У меня была такая же проблема со следующим сценарием: я хотел использовать ту же базу данных, что и приложение, из моих тестов интеграции.

Я пошел со следующим обходным путем:

В App.config моего тестового проекта у меня есть:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="DataDirectory" value="..\..\..\BookShop\App_Data\"/>
</appSettings>
```

В тестовой настройке я выполняю следующий код:

```
 var dataDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataDirectory"];  
   var absoluteDataDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(dataDirectory);  
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", absoluteDataDirectory);
```